# Centralizar uma div horizontal

Tags: css

Como centrar uma DIV horizontal, sem saber o width dela.

Exemplo:

Anterior - 1, 2, 3, 4 - Avançar

Comment: já tentou: margin: 0 auto; ?

Comment: Esta pergunta não tem qualquer relação com PHP.

Comment: Eu utilizo as técnicas que são listadas nesse artigo:
http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/ Foram muito úteis para mim.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução rápida, desde que você não se preocupe com semântica, seria usar o atributo **display:table**, em vez de **display:block** nas suas divs, assim:

```
<div id="paginador-wrapper">
    <div id="paginador-container">
        <!-- aqui vai a saída do seu código... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

No CSS, basta aplicar esses estilos:

```
#paginador-wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#paginador-container {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

A exibição como tabela e célula de tabela aceita a centralização nos mesmos moldes de uma tabela normal. Não é a solução mais linda do mundo, mas ainda é muito melhor do que trabalhar com posicionamentos e flutuações.

**Observação:** segundo o [w3scholls](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp), os valores "inline-table", "table", "table-caption", "table-cell", "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-row", e "table-row-group" não funcionam no IE7 e anteriores e no IE8 é preciso utilizar "!DOCTYPE" no html.

Comment: Já é conhecido aqui no SO-PT, que [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) não é uma boa referencia a ser utilizada, como já discutido [aqui no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/692/w3schools-%C3%A9-uma-refer%C3%AAncia-horr%C3%ADvel-certo), então recomendo que reveja o uso de referencia a ela, talvez substituindo por uma referencia ao [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/), que é mais aceito pela comunidade e muito mais atualizado.

Comment: @Fernando, a referência ao w3s é apenas quanto às restrições dos valores envolvidos na minha solução (que nada tem a ver com o w3s), especificamente relativas aos navegadores onde eles podem não funcionar. Se houver outras informações contrárias, será um prazer editar a observação. Obrigado pelo link e pela sugestão. Vou ler agora mesmo.