# Centralizar Horizontalmente

Tags: html, css, front-end, webdesign

Não consigo por nada centralizar minha div no meio da página!

Ja tentei usar o que postaram [nesse post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49589/centralizar-uma-div-dentro-de-outra-div-100), [nesse outro post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28124/centralizar-uma-div-horizontal), no [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) e em mais um monte de sites no google e não consigo centralizar a div horizontalmente.

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
     background-color: red;

}
body {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
/*Config da tela do login*/
.login-wrapper { 
    float: left; 
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;

}

.login-container {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

/*configuração do form login*/
.btn-acessar{
    background-color: darkred;
    color: white;
    width: 75%;
}
.link { 
    float: left; 
    clear: both; 
    width: 100%; 
    padding: 10px 0; 
}

.link a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
.input-login{
    width: 75%;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

form img{
    width: 75%;
    padding: 0 0 20px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>Titulo</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="login-wrapper">
            <div class="login-container">
                <form>
                    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control input-login" placeholder="Usuário">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control input-login" placeholder="Senha">
                    </div>
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-acessar">Acessar</button>
                </form>
                <div class="link">
                        <a href="#" class="col-xs-6">esqueci minha senha.</a>
                        <a href="#" class="col-xs-6">seja nosso cliente.</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
       </body>
</html>
```

Pra centralizar ele verticalmente eu usei JQuery, mas não queria fazer isso pra alinhar horizontalmente, queria poder alinhar ele só com CSS, mas não sei se fiz caca em algum lugar no código que não consegui alinhar com nada que tentei.

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Olhei um pouco por cima e vi que você tentou usar o margin:0 auto; na div .login-container, se você retirar o clear e o float a div irá ficar centralizada.

Comment: @haykou isso resolve, mas me deixa com outro problema. O conteúdo da div fica acompanhando o tamanho da tela, chegando em um momento que fica muito feio. Sabe como eu poderia fazer para limitar isso?

Comment: @haykou Estava a escrever uma resposta e só agora vi o teu comentário! Coloca uma resposta para poderes receber o devido crédito da solução :)

Comment: @AndreyHartung Vê a parte final da minha resposta que contém a solução para a questão da largura do elemento.

Comment: @Zuul , haha tranquilo, tua resposta tá mais explicativa.

Comment: @Zuul Eu vi, arrumei lá e depois que mexi em tudo eu lembrei o porque de ter colocado o float e o clear, o layout sem isso fica um pouco puxado para baixo uns 10/15px, o suficiente pra incomodar ver a tela...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Não desesperes, vieste ao sitio certo!</sup>

Para centrar o teu elemento, tem que te ver livre da propriedade `float` que tens no mesmo:

```
.login-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

O que está em cima é suficiente para o teu elemento ficar ao centro. O `float` vai flutuar o elemento para o lado indicado, quebrando o efeito do valor `auto` na propriedade `margin-right` e `margin-left`.

## Exemplo

Exemplo também disponível no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/b2pgd37o/), de fato assumindo melhor formatação.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red!important;
}
body {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
/*Config da tela do login*/
 .login-wrapper {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.login-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:60%;   /* adicionado para que o elemento possa ser visto centrado */
                     /* aqui no trecho de código da SE                          */
}
/*configuração do form login*/
 .btn-acessar {
    background-color: darkred;
    color: white;
    width: 75%;
}
.link {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.link a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
.input-login {
    width: 75%;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
form img {
    width: 75%;
    padding: 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="login-wrapper">
    <div class="login-container">
        <form>
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control input-login" placeholder="Usuário" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control input-login" placeholder="Senha" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-acessar">Acessar</button>
        </form>
        <div class="link"> <a href="#" class="col-xs-6">esqueci minha senha.</a>
 <a href="#" class="col-xs-6">seja nosso cliente.</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Nota:**
Presumo que a largura pretendida não seja essa, pois em ecrâs largos vai ficar "estranho", mas podes definir uma largura para o teu elemento:

```
.login-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:60%;
}
```

Ver [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/b2pgd37o/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Para você deixar um elemento centralizado horizontal e verticalmente tem de deixar ele como absoluto dentro de um elemento pai relativo, determinando altura de 100%.
E no elemento filho, absoluto, deve deixar com margem automática com valores 0.

Veja no código:

```css
/*Config da tela do login*/
 .login-wrapper {
    position: relative; // Elemento Pai RELATIVE
    height: 100%; // Altura 100 %
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid black;
    display: block; // Obrigatório quando se tem filhos com position ABSOLUTE.
}
.login-container {
    margin: auto; // Margin Automática 
    width:60%;   
    position: absolute; // Absolute - Obrigatório para centralizar verticalmente.
    height: 200px; // Obrigatório
    top: 0; // Valores 0, em todos.
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```